# iframe youtube not playing on ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, youtube

I am having problem to play youtube video in internet explorer 9 64 bits ?

Works well on chrome and firefox

I have read that adobe was not supported on ie6 64 bits, but it was more than a year ago, is there any settings to do to make it work on ie9 64 bits ?

I tried the test on this site

http://www.nvtgroup.co.uk/Seasons-Greetings.html

many other sites doesn' t work too

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [Adobe test page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-64-bit-operating.html).

It'll show the current system and plugin information (the image is just an example):

> Flash Player information
>
> If Flash Player is installed on your browser, the following box displays the version of Flash Player and your operating system. If Flash Player is not installed, an error message is displayed.
>
> [image]